# Hadoop Sandbox Hortonworks

Tags: linux, hadoop, windows-server-2008, redhat, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to Hadoop. Using `Windows Server 20008 R2` and `Oracle VirtualBox`, I imported an image of Hortonworks Sandbox and on Login, when it asks for username and password, I gave root and hadoop (as mentioned in documentations) but it doesn't log in somehow. It gives this screen which look like command prompt or something:

[image]

The question is, what do I do next? The documentation says you open a browser and type the URL but there's no Linnux screen appearing, this command prompt is the only thing displayed. Please help.

**EDIT:**

When I open the URL 127.0.0.1:8888/ in the browser, its like this:
[image]
Does't give any URL in the description above.

Answer (score 0):

Do an ifconfig and get the IP of your sandbox image.
Go to the browser and type http://IP_of_your_sandbox please ensure your sandbox gets a proper IP and not something like 127.0.0.1, if IP is 127.0.0.1 please check the network settings of your VM player.

On your browser you will be prompted to register the sandbox, post registration you will walk through a guided tutorial.
You can use either browser or terminal to execute the instructions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The IP of my Host is different. The VM UI is not appearing its just this command prompt there. ipconfig doesn't seem to work here it says unrecognized command. Plus please see the updated question, this might mae some sense to you..